# Using the old aspnet membership with aspnet vNext

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, membership-provider

**UPDATE November 20, 2015**

How can I authenticate against a database that have the users stored using the Old Membership Provider ?  (the aspnet_* tables)
Knowing that this database is used by other applications, so I don't have the option to migrate (or change) the database ?

For whom looking for migration look at **Maxime Rouiller**'s answer

**Old Question**

Can I use the aspnet Membership with aspnet vNext ?,

- In my situation I can't migrate the old database, because I am building a new app/ui interface for an existing one based on the old Membership provider
- It will be a good idea if I can write some code to login without using the old Membership
- What needed exactly is to just validate the user against the hashed password, (no registration, no forgot password, etc ...)
- I prefer to not rely on the `.net 4.x`, and using the `core50` (if available) instead (since I am planing to host it on linux later)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The old membership was dependent on the web.config being present and also was heavily dependent on the System.Web lifetime.

You are looking for a migration from your old membership to the new Identity 3.

The database should be easily portable. If you are planning to have it hosted on Linux, I would go as far as remove the `dnx451` dependency altogether and just keep `dnxcore50`.

#### Tutorials:

- http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity
- http://travis.io/blog/2015/03/24/migrate-from-aspnet-membership-to-aspnet-identity/

Comment: thanks for the helpful links, however as I mentioned before, migration is not an option for me

Comment: Then I highly recommend that you stay on `ASP.NET 4.*`. Otherwise you will absolutely need to migrate other parts of your app.

If you do need to host it on Linux, you'll need to do this anyway.

Comment: Actually what am doing is, creating another app based on asp.net vNext that use an existing database, this database is used by other apps that use the sql membership provider, for this reason I can't change the existing database

Comment: As far as my answer to your question goes... it's right on point. You can't reuse membership providers in ASP.NET 5. You'll need to migrate this component. Whether you can reuse the same database, that question deserves a different question.

Comment: Thanks I will accept yours as direct answer to my question, and I will update my question to be more clear.